# SVG Image with filter - filter covers area bigger than the image

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I have a problem with applying filters to an svg image. I'd like to apply a flood filter to just the image, but when I set that filter, it covers an area bigger than the image, seemingly increasing the size of the image. Is there a way to fix this? Run the snippet below to see the problem.

**One thing to note: the height of the image is unknown**

```css
image {
  outline: 3px solid red;
  outline-offset: -3px;
}

image.flood {
  filter: url(#floodFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="200" viewBox="0 0 500 200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="floodFilter" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <feFlood flood-color="lightblue" flood-opacity="1"></feFlood>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="floodFill" mode="multiply"></feBlend>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image x="0" y="30" width="200" href="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/140">   </image> 
  <image class="flood" x="230" y="30" width="200" href="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/140"></image>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the filter explicit bounds, the exact size of the object being filled.

By default the bounds are 10% bigger than the object so that drop shadows work.

Note that for your images to work cross-browser they will need height attributes.

```css
image {
  outline: 3px solid red;
  outline-offset: -3px;
}

image.flood {
  filter: url(#floodFilter);
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="200" viewBox="0 0 500 200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="floodFilter" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
      <feFlood flood-color="lightblue" flood-opacity="1" result="floodFill"></feFlood>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="floodFill" mode="multiply"></feBlend>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image x="0" y="30" height="140" width="200" href="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/140">   </image> 
  <image class="flood" x="230" y="30" height="140"  width="200" href="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/200/140"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your help. Is there a lookup somewhere for which browsers need the height? Currently I'm only concerned with Chrome, but that may change down the road...

Comment: everything except Chrome currently I believe.

Comment: Wow. Alrighty then, I should probably fix that now. Thanks again.